# jQuery hide li elements, then fade in on button hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a standard `ul` list which contains five `li` elements. After the third element, I've placed a button in the list with the CSS class `.morecats`.

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <button class="morecats">+</button>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Using jQuery, I have hidden the first three `li` elements:

```
$('ul')
  .find('li:gt(3)')
  .hide()
  .end();
```

Now, I'd like jQuery to fade in and show the hidden `li` elements when the user hovers over the button `.morecats`. I'd also like a separate div called `.bg`to fade in/appear.

How could this be accomplished?

Comment: button can't be a child of UL..is invalid html

Comment: ahh ...  but in all browsers? I bet versions of IE don't like it. You are asking for unexpected behavior

Comment: always stick to a valid html. `ul` can only have `li`s as child

Comment: you have to use Opacity
initially set 0 and animate it till 1

Comment: @charlietfl I haven't tried IE out yet, and you're most likely right. Unfortunately the ul in the above question is processed through a javascript function which only outputs innerHTML for the li elements that are contained within that one specific ul. Anything outside of the ul is not processed, and I don't have control over the javascript, so I have to use workarounds

Comment: to be certain it exists in proper location ( or exists at all) one workaround might be to remove original with your own code and create same button placed in valid parent

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. Button inside UL is invalid.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal  have you not read the 6 other comments about the valid html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be through the [jQuery hover function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).  The official example even has a fade in and fade out example you can look at.

```
$(".morecats").hover(
    function(){   // When the hover begins
        $('li').slice(-2).fadeIn(500);
    }, 
    function(){   // When the hover ends
        $('li').slice(-2).fadeOut(500);
    } 
);
```

The slice gets the last two `li` elements.

Jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/wDLVQ/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can achive it through `prevAll()` jQuery function:

You can read more here - **http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/**

```
$('ul')
.find('li:lt(3)')
.hide();           //<----------------------------first 3 li hidden

$(".morecats").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).prevAll('li').fadeIn(500); // when hover the button fadeIn the 
        $('.bg').fadeIn(500);              // hidden li and .bg div.
    },
    function(){ 
        $(this).prevAll('li').fadeOut(500); // used it to fadeout the first 3
    }                                       // lis again.
);
```